# Can't start a new activity with "findViewById" after updating

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HairvdoActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
           }
       });
    }
    }
```

I'm using the above code, but I can't open a new activity. My application is installing on my phone, but when I click on the button, the application stops/closes, and I don't know why.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: What happens when you click the button? What does your logcat say?

Comment: Could you put your HairvdoActivity class also ?

Comment: What’s your crash reason . Please give logcat message

Comment: You may have not registered HairvdoActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml or something might be causing NullPointerException in HairvdoActivity. You should share your logcat to be sure.

Comment: I've registered in AndroidManifest.xml, Still not working. I've used this code in many projects but in this project, i'm unable to use that. No errors are showing on the monitor. Some day's ago I was facing "findviewbyid_redundant" problem then this code works fine since. I've rechecked all the lines also rewrite some codes but nothing happens !!

Comment: show us the ful logcat

Comment: maybe the problem with that activity component not to the activity itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your device with desktop, run Android studio, reproduce the problem and look to Logcat window - do you see any exception?

In your case the application may be "dead" like this one:
http://joxi.ru/Dr8no6Ou4937x2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added your Hairvdoactivity in manifest file.

Its very important to register all Android Components in manifest. 
Like Activity, Services,BroadCastReceiver, etc.

Comment: I've done !! No results! It's happening after android studio update to 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It was an internal software hang problem. After restarted the MAC, then it solved. I'm thinking I'm using MacBook Pro but still facing the problem with simple coding. I've 350GB+ free storage!!!

Apple ??